# How can I suppress (particular) warnings for a particular class (and its subclasses)?

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, suppress-warnings

**The story**: I've learned that it's recommended to define all instance attributes in the `__init__()` function of a class for better clarity. And I've been following this best practice for a long time until I encounter this problem:

Let's say I have a base class `Foo`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = ...    # set initial values
        self.more_initialization()
    
    def more_initialization(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

So this base class will not be used directly, but its subclasses. Each of the subclasses may define its own instance attributes and initialize them in `more_initialization()`, so that I don't need to call `super().__init__()` on every inheritance.

*(This is just a very simple case; please refer to chepner's answer for some discussions.)*

But my linter (I'm using PyCharm) doesn't seem to be happy with that. It complains every time I assign value to an instance attribute not seen in `__init__()`:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    def more_initialization(self):
        self.d = 0      # warning: instance attribute defined outside __init__
    
    def work(self):
        self.d = 1      # same warning
```

**The question**: I wonder if there's any way to suppress such warnings for this particular case (`Foo` and all its subclasses), such as `# noqa` that will be identified by most linters. Developers subclassing `Foo` may not be all using the same IDE, and I don't want the unnecessary warnings to annoy them because it's guaranteed that `more_initialization()` will be called first before any other function.

Personally I use PyCharm, and there're two not-so-elegant ways to deal with this:

- Mark the function as protected by adding an underscore prefix (`_more_initialization()`)
- Set a rule that all subclasses of `Foo` must be placed in a file named with some pattern, and use this pattern to define a scope in which the warning is suppressed (also affecting other classes in the same files)

But I'm hoping for a general solution. Is there any?

In fact, it seems like I've been doing such kind of things for a while in `unittest`. I always define new instance attributes in `setUp()` before using them in my test cases, and the IDE never complains. How is that possible? Can I register my custom class/function for this?

Comment: Really, you should just take the conventional approach and override `Foo.__init__` with the appropriate call to `super().__Init__` instead of defining `more_initialization` instead. It only costs you one line of code, it makes it clearer how the subclasses are initialized, and you don't break inheritance.

Comment: @chepner you're probably right. But there can be more details of `__init__` that I would like to hide, e.g. args and kwargs.

Comment: It's starting to sound like you shouldn't be using inheritance in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

"More initialization" is what overriding `__init__` gives you. Your current approach causes more problems than it solve just to save one line of code per subclass.

Instead of

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = ...    # set initial values
        self.more_initialization()

class Bar(Foo):
    def more_intialization(self):
        ...
```

just use

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = ...    # set initial values

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        ...
```

Comment: It's just a simple case. If the `__init__` contains some arguments that the subclass is not interested in, I would like to hide such detail to the subclass.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If there is stuff relevant to the parent but not the child, then inheritance isn't appropriate.

Comment: it's just some arguments that are irrelevant to the child (e.g. __init__(self, a, b). The parent can still create some instance attributes that the child can use.

Comment: That's why [Python's `super()` considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) suggests using keyword arguments with `__init__`. Every `__init__` defines its own arguments and accepts `**kwargs` to pass anything else up the chain, until all keyword arguments are consumed by *someone* before `object.__init__` gets called.

Comment: I get your point. But there can be more complex cases. Let's say an `__init__` does three things `first`, `second`, `third` whose order must be kept, and I only want `second` to be overridable. How can I call `super().__init__` for this? Also it's more than `__init__` that this can happen: consider the `unittest` scenario I mentioned above.

Comment: Then you can override `second`, having it call `super().second` if appropriate/necessary.

Comment: Yeah, but the IDE just complains if I define some instance attributes in `second` which is considered outside `__init__`. (I've edited the question to add some of my findings.)

Comment: Frankly, that's more a problem with the IDE than with your code.